# Show message in parent page after closing popup child

Tags: javascript

I have this code in a child window (popup):

```
function confirmation() {
  var answer = confirm("Close?")
  if (answer) {
    var popup = window.open('../index.php?accao=some');
    popup.document.getElementById('boxid').style.visibility="visible";
  } else {
    return false;
  }
}
```

And, in the parent page I have:

```
<div id="boxid" style="visibility: hidden">Success</div>
```

What I want is to show the `#boxid` when I click in the popup to close. Why doesn't this code work?

UPDATE: still not working.

```
var popup = window.parent;
popup.document.getElementById('boxid').style.visibility="visible";
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `window.parent` to refer to the parent page.

What you are doing will open a new window.